# Can a sampling distribution have only 1 element or is it necessary to have multiple data elements to be a sampling distribution?

Tags: distributions, sampling, terminology

Can we have a sampling distribution of only 1 realization or is it necessary to have multiple data elements to be a sampling distribution?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Did you have a look at wikipedia's definition? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_distribution. *"It may be considered as the distribution of the statistic for all possible samples from the same population of a given sample size."*

Comment: A "sample" is not a "sampling distribution."  Could you therefore elaborate on what you mean by "have a sampling distribution"?

Comment: Yes and no. For example, there is life on Earth, so we know that life can exist on a planet. However, if we ask if life is entrenched on other planets, we cannot yet answer that in terms of how life is distributed. That is, we know that some distribution of life exists among planets, but what that distribution is, is unknown such that the probability of finding life on a given extraterrestrial planet is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

An example should clarify your confusion.

If we have a $N(0, 1)$ variable and draw four observations, we know that the sampling distribution of the mean is $N(0, 1/\sqrt{n}) = N(0, 1/2)$. When we actually make those four observations, we have made a single draw from $N(0, 1/2)$.

The sampling distribution is a theoretical idea, not something we observe. When we calculate the statistic, however, we are drawing a value from that theoretical distribution.

In order to generate the whole sampling distribution, we need to draw samples over and over. If you draw four observations from $N(0, 1)$, calculate the mean, and then repeat, you will wind up with many sample mean values. When you plot those values, the shape will look like $N(0, 1/2)$.

```
set.seed(2021)
N <- 4 # Sample size
R <- 1000 # Number of times to draw N samples from N(0, 1)
means <- rep(NA, R) 
for (i in 1:R){ # Loop R-many times

    x <- rnorm(N, 0, 1) # Draw N-many observations from N(0, 1)
    means[i] <- mean(x) # Calculate the mean of the N-many observations

}
hist(means) # Should look like N(0, 1/sqrt(N))
# Will look more like N(0, 1/sqrt(N) with larger R
```